# Como asignar una política IAM a una lambda - typescript

Tags: typescript, aws, lambda, dynamodb

Tengo una lambda que hace una llamada a putItem para insertar un registro en una tabla de una base de datos DynamoDB.

Me salta el siguiente error de acceso al ejecutarla:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: **** is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:***:table/*** because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:PutItem action
```

Necesito asignar una política a mi lambda, exactamente una que pueda realizar la función putItem en DynamoBD. No sé como hacerlo.

Este es mi código de la lambda:

```
export class NewPlatformIoTCoreStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
      super(scope, id, props);

      // Rule of IoT Core for MQTT sending of the devices
      
      const constructProps: IotToLambdaProps = {
        lambdaFunctionProps: {
          code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../lambdasCode/mqttBroker/')),
          runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
          handler: 'index.handler'
        },
        iotTopicRuleProps: {
          topicRulePayload: {
            ruleDisabled: false,
            description: "Processing of MQTT messages from AWS IoT Stack",
            sql: "SELECT *, topic(4) as device_id FROM 'v1/data/1'",
            actions: []
          }
        }
      };
     
    new IotToLambda(this, 'iot-lambda-integration', constructProps);
      
  };  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el panel de la lambda en AWS, ve a la pestaña "Configuración" y ahí busca la sección "Permisos". Ahí podrás ver el rol que tiene asociada la Lambda. Este rol es el que se encarga de asignarle los permisos de ejecución.

Verás que el rol tiene el nombre en azul, es un enlace. Si haces click se te cargará la página de dicho rol y ahí podrás configurarlo para darle o quitarle permisos.

Dado que los permisos van por rol y no por lambda, si este rol es compartido por otros recursos, todos ellos tendrán acceso a los mismos recursos

Comment: perfecto, muchas gracias! Una duda, ¿es posible hacer este proceso de asignacion desde el código fuente?

Comment: Desde la propia lambda? No. Cuestiones de seguridad. Eso sería como darle a tu hijo de 13 años una tarjeta de crédito para evitarte la molestia de tener que bajar tu al cajero cuando le tienes que dar la paga

Comment: Además, esos cambios tardan unos segundos en aplicarse y ese lapso de tiempo para una lambda es algo inmenso ... no creo que quisieses pagar por que en cada ejecución de la lambda se reconfiguren los permisos

Comment: perfecto, más claro agua, muchas gracias!